# VSTO how to populate XML ribbon combobox on load?

Tags: c#, xml, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbon

I am working on trying to load a list of items (preferably from a file like csv, etc.) and fill in a combobox with those items.  Then I want to be able to grab the text of the selected item.  I have routinely done this fine in other C# projects, but it seems it does not work the same way in VSTO xml.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Edit to add code... I found the RibbonDropDownItem interface which it seems is required to add an item, but the C# below wont work because it cant find the cboItems object in the XML.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
                <group id="group1" label="Work Orders">
                    <dropDown id="cboItems" label="Select a work order:"
                               getItemLabel="GetItemLabel"
                               getItemCount="GetItemCount"
                               onAction="OnSendUsingAction"
                               >
                    </dropDown>
                    <button id="btnSelect" label="Submit" 
                     onAction="ButtonClick"/>
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

```
private List<string> workOrders = new List<string>();
public void Ribbon_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
    {
        this.ribbon = ribbonUI;
    }

    public void OnSendUsingAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, string value, int index)
    {
        if (value == "cboItems")
            selectedWorkOrder = workOrders[index];
    }

    public void ButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(selectedWorkOrder);
    }

    public string GetItemLabel(Office.IRibbonControl control, int index)
    {
        return workOrders[index];
    }

    public int GetItemCount(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return workOrders.Count();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For combobox with variable number of items, you need to specify `getItemCount` / `getItemLabel` / `getSelectedItemIndex` / `onAction` callbacks:

```xml
<dropDown id="someId" label="some label"
               showLabel="false" 
               getItemImage="GetItemImage"
               getItemCount="GetItemCount"
               getItemLabel="GetItemLabel"
               getSelectedItemIndex="GetSelectedItemIndex"
               onAction="OnSendUsingAction"
               sizeString= "Some long string to size the control"
             >
```

Comment: Thank you.  I can see this will help some with what I am trying to accomplish, but in the code side, how do I create the items that get added to the combo box?

Comment: When your `getItemLabel` callback is executed, you will receive the control and the index as parameters. It is your responsibility to return a string representing an item with the given index.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I understand what to do when I select an item, but I am still stuck on how to populate the list with the items so that i can select them.

Comment: What is your latest ribbon xml and code?

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: But you have not implemented getItemCount / getItemLabel callbacks

Comment: I updated again.  I implemented some of the callbacks, but when using this code, I no longer even receive the Ribbon_Load callback, and my ribbon doesn't even display anymore.

Comment: Try to enable ribbon errors in "File | Options | Advanced | Developers | Show user interface errors" and restart Outlook.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion it helped me identify i needed to use a drop down instead of a combobox.  I now can see the object in the ribbon.  However, when clicking the drop down, none of the callbacks are entered.  I updated the code in the original post.

Comment: You must also implement getItemCount callback - otherwise Outlook assumes you have 0 items.

Comment: I updated the code again.  I can get into the getItemCount callback now.  So how do I add items to the dropDown now that I have a reachable callback? I still don't see a way to interact with my xml objects.

Comment: `GetItemCount` must return an int, not a void. Once you do that, `GetItemLabel` will be called multiple times with the corresponding index (0 through Count-1), and you are supposed to return a string with the given index. You need to fix the signature of both methods.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/700e4451-8706-40c5-8d7b-896e4ae21b69

Comment: `public int GetItemCount(IRibbonControl control)`

Comment: `public string GetItemLabel(IRibbonControl control, int index)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with me, Dmitry.  I am very close now after your last suggestion.  I am able to populate the list and select an item.  However, I do not know how to grab the label of the item I have selected when I press my button.  Thoughts? the original post has been updated again....

Comment: You need to store the last item selected in your code when `onAction` fires (you need to update the method signature) - it will pass the index and the string: `public void OnSendUsingAction(Office.IRibbonControl control, string value, int index) `

Comment: When I add the extra parameters to the signature, I get an error.  'Callback signature mismatch: "OnSendUsingAction" '  I added the same callback to the DropDown object.  However, it only passes in the object name 'cboItems' and the selected index.  How do I get the string of the item in the selected index?

Comment: What is your latest code and XML?

Comment: I forgot that I already had the list of items from earlier on, so I could just use the index to look at that, my bad.  I think finally my question has been answered and I have a solution.